# CSS: set max-width to 220px, OR 50% if 220px will be more than 50% of the view

Tags: css

I'm trying to set the width of my images to 220px, unless the view (forexample on an iphone) will make the 220px take more than 50% of the screen width.

If i set the image to 220px max-width, it will take more than 50% of the screen width of an iPhone 6 4.7" forexample. So in that case, I want the CSS rule to be max-width: 50%, not 220px.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 220px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using CSS' media queries:

```
img {
    width: 220px;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 439px) {
    img {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

This rule should set the width of all `<img>` elements to `220px`; on devices for which `220px` would be more than half (hence selecting a `max-device-width` of `439px` `(2 x 220) - 1`) it will override the previous rule, and set the width of `<img>` elements to `50%` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
img {
    width: 220px;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Currell/qpmLdkuu/1/